# Jquery add class to 5 last elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

i have lots of images:

```
<img src="images/img.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/img3.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/img4.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/img5.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/img6.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/img7.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/img8.jpg" alt="" />
```

and so on...

How to add class only to last five images?

Thanx

Comment: unfortunately i don't even know from where to start, it is easy to add class to first, last, even, odd, but don't know how to add to last five :(

Comment: Read the documentation. Browse the methods. You will find what you're looking for.

Comment: I will look at documentation, for future. Thanx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) for that:

```
$("img").slice(-5).addClass("myclass");
```

Comment: +1 I have to agree (at least for simple and clear, for efficient I don't know but that hardly matters) :)

Comment: @dystroy I mean compared to iterating over the whole array and testing the index

Comment: @LiviuT. I don't want to sound critical, as I find this is a better answer than mine, but I'm really doubtful about the performances gain : we can't know without profiling but making a new collection isn't always faster than iterating over the elements. But once again, there won't be performance problems here...

Comment: I agree too :) Simply awesome!

Comment: @dystroy Your code is more efficient, however, it selects more than the last 5 elements. http://jsperf.com/last-5-elements

Comment: @dystroy - Not a criticism, but note that in your answer you create a new jQuery object on every iteration so you don't just iterate over elements either.

Comment: @David - in the jsperf link you setup, in Chrome, the `.slice()` answer came out as more efficient - it says the loop is 40% slower... (+1 to VisioN, by the way.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: I was wondering if using a native for loop and `eq` would perform close to slice. Works in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/2L5tS/ but the updated jsperf hates the syntax http://jsperf.com/last-5-elements/2 would have been nice to see how it performs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery filter [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLL4V/)

```
var lastimageIndex = $('img').length -1;
$('img').filter(function(index) {
    console.log(lastimageIndex - index - 6 < 0);
   return lastimageIndex - index - 5 < 0;
}).addClass("yourclass");​
```